# Putting an enable input on a decoder (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, decoder

I have a 4 to 16 decoder in vhdl. I want to put an enable input but I'm new to vhdl coding. I want to keep this structure of the code (I don't want to any other shortcuts, or completely altered code). I tried writing a `e` input for the enable, and tried doing `if e = "1" then` but it doesn't work.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
entity decode4to16 is
port(
oct : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
e : in std_logic;
dec : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));
end decode4to16;
architecture arch of decode4to16 is
begin
if e = "1" then
with oct select
dec <=
"0000000000000001" when "0000",
"0000000000000010" when "0001",
"0000000000000100" when "0010",
"0000000000001000" when "0011",
"0000000000010000" when "0100",
"0000000000100000" when "0101",
"0000000001000000" when "0110",
"0000000010000000" when "0111",
"0000000100000000" when "1000",
"0000001000000000" when "1001",
"0000010000000000" when "1010",
"0000100000000000" when "1011",
"0001000000000000" when "1100",
"0010000000000000" when "1101",
"0100000000000000" when "1110",
"1000000000000000" when "1111",
"0000000000000000" when others;
end if;
end arch;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use proper indentation in the futur, to ease reading.

An if statement can only be used in a process, and as @Josh pointed out, *e* is a **std_logic**, which requires single quote when verifying or assigning it's value. The final results is something like:

```
DECODER: process(e, oct) -- e and oct are in sensitivity list, which means output the process statements are executed whenever one of these change
begin
    if e = '1' then
        case oct is
            when "0000" => dec <= X"0001";
            when "0001" => dec <= X"0002";
            ...
            when others => dec <= X"0000";
        end case;
    end if;
end process DECODER;
```

On a side note, this will create a *latch*, since there is an implicit behaviour that a signal's value will not change when it is not assigned. In this case, this happens when *e* is '0'; i.e. there is no else in your statement. This is probably not what you want, and should assign a value to *dec* when *e* is '0'.